# How I can print directly the value from database sql server. I am using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

```
Sub Data_Load()
    dtItem = New DataTable
    With dtItem.Columns
        .Add("itemname", Type.GetType("System.String"))
        .Add("qty", Type.GetType("System.String"))
        .Add("price", Type.GetType("System.String"))
        .Add("lblname", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    End With

    Dim ItemRow As DataRow

    ItemRow = dtItem.NewRow()
    ItemRow("itemname") = "Taro Snack"
    ItemRow("qty") = "1"
    ItemRow("price") = "70000"
    dtItem.Rows.Add(ItemRow)

    ItemRow = dtItem.NewRow()
    ItemRow("itemname") = "Kopi Ice"
    ItemRow("qty") = "2"
    ItemRow("price") = "7000"
    dtItem.Rows.Add(ItemRow)

    ItemRow = dtItem.NewRow()
    ItemRow("itemname") = "Lolipop"
    ItemRow("qty") = "5"
    ItemRow("price") = "1000"
    dtItem.Rows.Add(ItemRow)

End Sub
```

I just edit my code, this is my code. I just want to select from database and print without print preview

[image: 1]

Comment: *"without display the table print"*. What does that actually mean? I don't see anything being displayed there. I see you apparently printing (no idea how that class you're using is designed) data from a `DataTable`. If you have populated that table from a database then you're printing data from that database. I don't see what the actual problem is, because you haven't explained what the actual problem is.

Comment: I want to select the data for item, qty, price and subtotal from database, so I don't have to put manually for  item, qty, price and subtotal  like this                             
        ItemRow = dtItem.NewRow()
        ItemRow("itemname") = "Taro Snack"
        ItemRow("qty") = "1"
        ItemRow("price") = "70000"
        dtItem.Rows.Add(ItemRow)

Comment: Don't explain your question in a comment. That's what the question is for. Edit your question and provide the FULL and CLEAR explanation that you should have provided in the first place. No one should have to read the comments to understand the question.

Comment: The fact that you have no badges indicates that you didn't take the site tour when prompted. That was a mistake. You should do so now and also spend some additional time in the Help Center to learn what is required of a good question. The better your question, the more likely you'll get the help you want. Bad questions will likely be closed and they waste our time, making it less likely that we'll help you in the future as well.

Comment: Can you confirm this maybe, see if I understand.  You currently have some code where values are hard coded in the Data_Load() method.  You want to update that method to query a database and populate dtItem with the records relevant to that transaction number?

Comment: I just edit my code, and upload some picture so may be you can help me to understand

Comment: This question has nothing to do with printing. Your question is how to retrieve data from a database into a `DataTable`. That is something that you can easily find out how to do if you actually search for it using those keywords. Any tutorial on ADO.NET will show you how to do that as it is the most fundamental operation in any database development.

Comment: By the way, don't use the `Type.GetType` method like that. You should be using the `GetType` operator, which takes a data type rather than a `String` and thus allows the compiler to validate the argument: `.Add("itemname", GetType(String))`.

Comment: Also by the way, your code to add rows is very verbose. If you did want to add a row, it would take one line: `dtItem.Rows.Add("Lolipop", "5", "1000", DBNull.Value)`. Not sure whether the last value is required if it's NULL, but I think you do need to provide a value for every column.

Comment: Finally, why are you using `String` as the data type for columns that clearly represent numbers? DO NOT use `String` for things that are not `Strings`. If a column is supposed to store values that represent whole numbers then use `Integer`, etc.

Comment: Querying a database and printing data are two completely separate topics so no question should involve both. Regarding the printing part though, you have to write code specifically to provide print preview functionality so, if you don't want a preview, don't write code to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show you the sql code I had to make some assumptions. I assumed that the `TransNo` would identify the items you are looking for. I created a `DataTable` with a computed column, `subtotal`.

That long list of class level variables is not necessary. Variables do not need to be at the class level unless they are needed in more than one method. Scope variables as narrowly as possible.

I used several interpolated strings. They are preceded by a `$` and variables can be inserted in line surrounded by `{ }` braces. I think they make the code easier to read without all the quotes and ampersands.

```
Private ConStr As String = "Your connection string"
Private TransNo As String = "TCN10-20191204-001"

Private Function Data_Load() As DataTable
    Dim dtItem As New DataTable
    With dtItem.Columns
        .Add("itemname", GetType(String))
        .Add("qty", GetType(Integer))
        .Add("price", GetType(Decimal))
        .Add("subtotal", GetType(Decimal), "qty * price")
    End With
    Using con As New SqlConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As New SqlCommand("Select itemname, qty, price From YourTableName Where TransNo = @TransNo", con)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@TransNo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TransNo
        con.Open()
        Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            dtItem.Load(reader)
        End Using
    End Using
    Return dtItem
End Function

Private Sub btnPrint_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPrint.Click
    Dim dt = Data_Load()
    Dim c As New PrintingFormat
    Printer.NewPrint()
    Dim Img As Image = Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath() & "\logo.jpg")
    Printer.Print(Img, 200, 100)
    'Setting Font
    Printer.SetFont("Courier New", 11, FontStyle.Bold)
    Printer.Print(StoreName)
    'Setting Font
    Printer.SetFont("Courier New", 11, FontStyle.Bold)
    'Setting Font
    Printer.SetFont("Courier New", 8, FontStyle.Regular)
    Printer.Print(StoreAddress & ";", {280}, 0)
    'spacing
    Printer.Print(" ")
    Printer.Print(TransNo)
    Printer.Print(Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
    Printer.Print(" ")
    Printer.SetFont("Courier New", 8, FontStyle.Bold)
    Dim arrWidth = {90, 40, 50, 70}
    Dim arrFormat As StringFormat() = {c.MidLeft, c.MidRight, c.MidRight, c.MidRight}
    Printer.Print("item;qty;price;subtotal", arrWidth, arrFormat)
    Printer.SetFont("Courier New", 8, FontStyle.Regular)
    Printer.Print("------------------------------------")
    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        Printer.Print($"{row("itemname")};{row("qty")};{row("price")};{row("subtotal")}", arrWidth, arrFormat)
    Next
    Dim sum = CDec(dt.Compute("SUM(subtotal)", String.Empty))
    Printer.Print("------------------------------------")
    arrWidth = {130, 120}
    arrFormat = {c.MidLeft, c.MidRight} 'array alignment 
    Printer.Print($"Total;{sum}", arrWidth, arrFormat)
    Printer.Print($"Payment;50000", arrWidth, arrFormat)
    Printer.Print("------------------------------------")
    Dim Change = 50000 - sum
    Printer.Print($"Change;{Change}", arrWidth, arrFormat)
    Printer.Print(" ")
    Dim TotalItems = CInt(dt.Compute("SUM(qty)", String.Empty))
    Printer.Print($"Item Qty;{TotalItems}", arrWidth, arrFormat)
    'Release the job for actual printing
    Printer.DoPrint()
End Sub
```